# Fancybox; How can I style the fancybox-inner property? Looks like it's already being styled somehow

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Here's the image of what I'm seeing, might make it very clear on what's going on:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDKGj.jpg

(Click to zoom)

Basically, looking at the fancybox-inner property, and am wanting to style it to reduce the size of the image inside the fancybox, instead of resizing the image itself.

I'll then be trying to add a sidebar area to the right of the fancybox where the user can click a "Download Hi-Res Image", and download the high-res version, but that's the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `beforeShow` callback to set a new size of the image on the fly like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function() {
        var newWidth = 250; // set new image display width
        $(".fancybox-inner img").css({
            width  : newWidth,
            height : "auto"
        }); // apply new size to img
        // optionally :
        // set new values for parent container IF you want to match the image size
        // this.width  = newWidth;
        // this.height = $(".fancybox-inner img").innerHeight();
    }
}); // fancybox​
```

**NOTE** : this is for fancybox v2.1.3+

Comment: I noticed today, after implementing this late last night, that sometimes the fancybox (when I click the image) will come up and be very small height-wise.

Other times, it's just fine. I'll click through the gallery, and it seems as though it just randomly happens.

Just wondering if anyone else has encountered this? Is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

a quick 'hack' seems to get it working, and while not the complete solution, it should be a good starting ground for you.

in the jquery.fancybox.css file, add at the bottom of the file the following to limit the image width to 300px..

```
.fancybox-skin,
.fancybox-outer,
.fancybox-inner{max-width:300px;margin:0 auto;}
```